# Using spark context outside main

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm sorry if this is an elementary question but I could not find an answer searching for it or I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I have two files in a program: main.scala and second.scala

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    /*load spark conf*/
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("main")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    }
}
```

in a separate file

```
object second {
    val somelist = list(1,2,3)
    sc.parallelize(somelist)
}
```

I want to create and RDD in the second file but I cant call sc because it is out of scope? (no matter where I put sc or what imports I use)

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc` is a method variable which exists only inside the method `main`. to use sc you will have to pass the context object as a parameter to a method as shown below.

```
object Second {
 def createRDD(sc: SparkContext) = {
    val somelist = list(1,2,3)
    sc.parallelize(somelist)
  }
}
```

call method `createRDD` in `main`

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    /*load spark conf*/
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("main")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    Second.createRDD(sc)
    }
}
```